# Issue finding .html resource in Maven using Spring

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, resources

New to using Maven/Spring, and messing around trying to create a simple web app. I've got an index.html which I've added to src/main/resources/templates, as well as the main Application, Controller etc.

I'm also using cucumber to do testing, and one of the steps is to GET "http://localhost/billparser/index". I've also set up an application.properties file under src/main/resource, with the entry:

```
#server.contextPath=/billparser
```

However I get these lines of logging out:

```
17:41:47.935 [main] DEBUG o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler - Trying relative path [index] against base location: ServletContext resource [/]
17:41:47.935 [main] DEBUG o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler - Trying relative path [index] against base location: class path resource [META-INF/resources/]
17:41:47.936 [main] DEBUG o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler - Trying relative path [index] against base location: class path resource [resources/]
17:41:47.936 [main] DEBUG o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler - Trying relative path [index] against base location: class path resource [static/]
17:41:47.936 [main] DEBUG o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler - Trying relative path [index] against base location: class path resource [public/]
```

I've checked, and my index.html file has been put into target/classes/templates. 
I've done some googling online but I'm new to any of this sort of stuff, and seem a little bewildered. I'm using https://github.com/excellentdrums/Cucumber-JVM-Spring-MVC-Test-HTMLUnit-Demo as a bit of a template for getting it working, and followed what he's done but having no luck myself.

I've done some googling but I'm still lost. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thank you.

Pom.xml looks as such:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.tmh.bill</groupId>
<artifactId>billParser</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Bill Parser</name>
<description>Parse out a JSON to show a bill.</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.RC5</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test-mvc-htmlunit</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.M1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.6</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.6</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.40.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <start-class>bill.Application</start-class>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestone</id>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestone</id>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Comment: To load a html file you really just need to place the file in your resources/template (which I believe you have done) then have a controller with a request mapping for that file and then have a look at this link, especially from section 3 onwards, basically you need a      bean defined in an XML file with a InternalResourceViewResolver.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I have a basic index controller, which consists of the following:

`@Controller
@RequestMapping("/index")
public class IndexController {

 @RequestMapping("/index")
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }

}`

Comment: Also @smoggers, can you post the link please? Thank you!

Comment: yeah apologies for that here it is http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/mvc/spring-mvc-view-resolver-example/

Answer (score 0):

A Spring Boot application starts up on port 8080 by default. Also, the `server.contextPath` property in your `application.properties` file is commented out, so this does not affect your context path. The correct URL for you should be http://localhost:8080/index, as long as you have the `/index` path mapped in your controller.

You can test this by running [the example GitHub project you referenced](https://github.com/excellentdrums/Cucumber-JVM-Spring-MVC-Test-HTMLUnit-Demo) and navigating to http://localhost:8080/hello, which will give you the following:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've tried setting the test to GET http://localhost:8080/hello, however I now get a null pointer when trying to get the servlet path (as the servletPath is now null). Do I need a servlet path, and if so, how do I get it to set correctly? The GitHub project I referenced tests using localhost/greetings/hello - I'm basically following the same architecture, and his app can pick up the html files whereas mine can't. Am I missing something obvious? Thanks again for your response + time.

Comment: I see now. I'm not too sure how that happens, but it did work for me on the example project by using [localhost:8080/greeting/hello](http://localhost:8080/greeting/hello), regardless of the contents of the `application.properties` file. What happens if you use either `http://localhost/billParser/index` or `http://localhost:8080/billParser/index` (with the 'P' capitalized)?

Comment: Ah I see the other one is working. Unfortunately, I've tried with mine (using `localhost/index`, `localhost:8080/index`, `localhost:8080/billParse/index` and variations, but I just get 404s. Not sure what I'm missing!